# AngularJS accessing localStorage the right way

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authentication, promise, local-storage

I'm making an application with Node.js backend and AngularJS frontend. I have gotten the login to work but now I have a problem with displaying the data from localStorage. When I log in i'm saving the user info into the localStorage and it's working fine, but when the user is redirected to the profile page I have to refresh the page to see the users name and other info. So the problem is displaying the localStorage data to the HTML.

My AngularJS file:

```
var application = angular.module('application', ['ngRoute', 'ngStorage', 'ngAnimate', 'angularUtils.directives.dirPagination']);

application.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

  $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');

    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl : "views/home.html",
        //controller: "appController"
      })
      .when('/login', {
        templateUrl : "views/login.html",
        controller: "loginController"
      })
      .when('/profile', {
        templateUrl: "views/profile.html",
        controller: "sessionController"
      }).when('/logout', {
        templateUrl: "views/logout.html",
        controller: "logoutController"
      }).otherwise({
        redirectto: "/home"
      });

      $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

}]);

application.controller('loginController',  function($scope, $location, $http, $localStorage, $window) {

    $scope.formData = {};

    $scope.userLogin = function() {

        $scope.formData.email = $scope.email;
        $scope.formData.password = $scope.password;

        $http.post('/login', $scope.formData).
        then(function(response) {
          $localStorage.userData = response.data;
          $location.path("/profile");
        }).catch(function(response) {
          console.log(response);
          $location.path("/login");
          $scope.error = "fail"
        });
    }
});

application.controller('sessionController', function($scope, $location, $http, $localStorage, $window) {

  var getUserData = new Promise (function(resolve, reject) {
    var result = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("ngStorage-userData"));
    //console.log(result);
    resolve(result);
  });

  $scope.getData = function() {
    getUserData.then(function(response) {
        $scope.currentUserData = response;
        $scope.$apply();
        console.log($scope.currentUserData);
//THIS PRINTS NULL THE FIRST TIME SOMEONE LOGINS
    });
  }
});

application.controller('logoutController', function($scope, $location, $http, $localStorage, $window) {

        $window.localStorage.clear();
});
```

And my profile page view:

```
<div class="col-md-12" style="width:500px;" ng-init="getData()">
    <div align="right"><a ng-href="/logout">Logout</a></div>
      <h4>Welcome {{ currentUserData.personal.firstname }}! </h4>
    <p><strong>This is Profile page Page</strong></p>
</div>
```

So the first time someone logs in the application prints null for the $scope.currentUserData. When the page refreshes it prints it normally and I can see the info in the profile page. Can someone help me what am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you seem to be a bit missing the point of local storage.

You don't need localStorage to pass data between angular states. For that you have angular services - implement one. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services

localStorage is needed to preserve information over application reload.

Secondly, you are mixing angularjs with vanilla js promises. As you are obviously beginning your angular experience - I'd advice against it. Use angularjs all the way, until you will find a real need not to: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Thirdly, if you have to use $scope.$apply() or $scope.$digest() - you probably doing something wrong. You should be able to get by w/o those for simple applications.

Try to follow these 3 points and see if you can rewrite the code.

Comment: Thanks for your response :)